# Summing a list of strings in Python

Tags: python, string, list, sum

I have a list containing this kind of lists:

```
l = [['709', '651', '750', '806', '850', '759', '801'],
     ['603', '551', '600', '555', '559', '655', '700'],
     ['603', '-', '-', '601', '-', '-', '-']]
```

And I want a new list containing the sum of every individual list.

In this case, the result should be:

```
[5326, 4223, 1204]
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Is this Python, Javascript or something else?

Comment: yeah sorry forgot, it's python

Comment: Sounds like you would have to use a `for` loop over each array and sum up the elements.

Answer (score 6):

```
lists = [
    ['709', '651', '750', '806', '850', '759', '801'],
    ['603', '551', '600', '555', '559', '655', '700'],
    ['603', '-', '-', '601', '-', '-', '-']
]

lists_sum = [sum(int(i) for i in l if i != '-') for l in lists]
```

Answer (score 2):

More appropriate:

```
lists = [
    ['709', '651', '750', '806', '850', '759', '801'],
    ['603', '551', '600', '555', '559', '655', '700'],
    ['603', '-', '-', '601', '-', '-', '-']
]

lists_sum = [sum(int(i) for i in l if i.isdigit()) for l in lists]
```

Comment: Nope. a) i.isidigit() is a better form (since str.isdigit(None) throws a TypeError anyway), and even then b) what about negative number, or floats.

Comment: oh i missed it, i will Update my answer.